# SSRS display one of two possible dates

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a confirmation letter used to display one of two dates to a customer.
Date.Value is the purchase date of a product not tied to a finite inventory.
InventoryDate.Value is the date an activity is taking place, based on inventory availability.
Everything has a purchase date, but not everything has an inventory date. I would like the letter to display InventoryDate.Value if it has one, or display Date.Value if inventory date is null. I've played around with a bunch of variations in my code, but what I currently have is:

```
=iif( Fields!InventoryDate.Value="", Fields!Date.Value, Fields!InventoryDate.Value)
```

This is displaying Date.Value correctly, but returning #Error for any product with an Inventory Date. I am very new to SSRS/Reporting, so please keep any suggestions at a newb understanding level.

Working in MS Report Builder.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Try testing if the date equals nothing `Fields!InventoryDate.Value=Nothing` . If this does not help, as with anything date related, please confirm the data types `InventoryDate` and `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data type of the fields, they can be blank or empty. With ="" you are only checking, if the field is blank.

try this:

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!InventoryDate.Value),Fields!Date.Value,Fields!InventoryDate.Value)
```